# json.stringify(obj) error obj is not defined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access an element of an object but whenever I do the code throws an `undefined` error.

```
var pokeShow= function(pokaName,datapp) {
         for(var i=0;i<datapp.pokemon.length;i++) {
         if(datapp.pokemon[i].name==pokaName){
          var dispo=datapp.stringify(pokemon[i])   // this line is showing error that pokemon is not defined 
          alert(dispo)
         }

        else
          alert("wrong input")
    }
```

the json file(a block of it):-

```
var pokeData = {
  "pokemon": [{
    "id": 1,
    "num": "001",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "img": "http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/pokemon/001.png",
    "type": [
      "Grass",
      "Poison" ...
```

Pokemon seems to be clearly defined in the object, why is this error being thrown?

Comment: `pokemon` is not a standalone variable, it is a property of another object

Comment: care to explain?? i am new to this

Comment: in your if clause you use `datapp.pokemon[i]` but when stringify you only use `pokemon[i]`?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO! You can help other users help you by clearly formulating a question to they have a better idea of where to start.

Comment: var pokeShow= function(pokaName,datapp) {
     for(var i=0;i<datapp.pokemon.length;i++) {
     if(datapp.pokemon[i].name==pokaName){
      var dispo=datapp.stringify(datapp.pokemon[i])  --->> still giving error
      alert(dispo)

Comment: `var dispo=JSON.stringify(datapp.pokemon[i])`

Comment: You should know more about your variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It seems you are trying to get part of an object that you haven't defined as it's own.**

```
datapp.pokemon[i].name==pokaName
pokemon[i]
```

Try replacing

```
var dispo=datapp.stringify(pokemon[i])
```

with

```
var dispo=datapp.stringify(datapp.pokemon[i])
```

Also, I am not entirely sure but I think you meant to put **JSON.stringify instead of datapp.stringify**

Comment: ohh gosh.. been up with this all night..it was just a typo.. thanks anyway.. its working now. cheers !!

Comment: Glad I could get this working for you :>). If you found this helpful please tag it as the answer so future lookers can find it. Make sure to get some rest!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0;i<datapp.pokemon.length;i++) {
  if(datapp.pokemon[i].name==pokaName){
    var dispo=datapp.stringify(pokemon[i]) 
      alert(dispo)
  }
}
```

`pokemon` is an array which is part of `datapp`, which you're doing right when you're comparing `if(datapp.pokemon[i].name==pokaName)`. The problem is when you `stringify` it, you're not referring to `datapp.pokemon[i]` and hence the undefined. Instead you can change it to below

```
    var dispo=JSON.stringify(datapp.pokemon[i])
```